# How to paste literal words in Tcl

Tags: syntax, tcl

Is there any syntax trick / feature which would allow me to paste two *literal* words in TCL, e.g. to concatenate a braced (`{..}`) word and a double-quoted `"..."`) word into a single one?

I'm not asking about `set a {foo}; set b "bar\nquux"; set c $a$b` or `append a $b` -- I know about them; but about something without intermediate variables or commands. Analogous to the `{*}word` (which turns a word into a list).

I guess that the answer is "no way", but my shallow knowledge of Tcl doesn't allow me to draw such a conclusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to do what you're asking for without a command, since the syntax of braced words doesn't permit anything before or afterwards, and once you have several words you need to join them with a command (because that's what commands do from the perspective of Tcl's language core; take some values and produce a value result). Not that having braces in the middle of a string is syntax error — it isn't — but it does stop them being quote characters. To be clear:

1. `puts a{b}` prints `a{b}` because `{` is *not special* in that case and instead becomes part of the value.
2. `puts {a}b` is a syntax error. (The *only* exception to this is `{*}`, which started as `{expand}` but that was *waaaay* too wordy.)

Approaches that work:

- Use `string cat`.
- Use a concatenation procedure (e.g., `proc strcat {a b} {return $a$b}`
- Put both values inside the braces so it is a combined literal. Which only works if you have both parts being literals, of course.
- Convert the braced part to non-braced (and non-double-quoted) form. This is *always* possible as every braced string has a non-braced equivalent, but can involve a *lot* of backslashes.

Comment: One could add using a backflip using `return -level 0 $a$b`, no need for a dedicated `proc` or `string cat`.

Comment: This matches the research I did since posting the Q, so I'll say that this is the answer. At least until someone comes and show that we're both wrong and are missing something obvious ;-)

Comment: While `return -level 0` works (quite well actually)… we added `string cat` exactly so that we won't have to remember that particular obscurity.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a recent Tcl version (8.6.2 or newer) you can use

```
set c [string cat {foo} "bar\nquux"]
```

For older versions, you can resort to

```
set c [format %s%s {foo} "bar\nquux"]
```

Comment: You can also make your own string concatenator: `proc strcat {a b} {return $a$b}` or more generally: `proc strcat args {join $args ""}`

Answer (score 0):

If your word is a valid list, you can do:

```
set orig {abc def}
set new [join $orig {}]
```